# How to add a custom block on sales order's create page inside admin panel?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, sales-order

I want to add a custom block on sales order's create page under admin section.

*Here is my code:*

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>

    <reference name="sidebar">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="verification" template="magentomod/ageverification/sales/order/create/comment.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>

    <reference name="sidebar">
        <block type="adminhtml/template" name="verification" template="magentomod/ageverification/sales/order/create/comment.phtml"/>
    </reference>

</adminhtml_sales_order_create_load_block_data>
```

It's working fine but if I change the reference from **sidebar** to **content** or data **block**, it stops working. I want to add this block within content block.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What else is in the content block under those layout handles? Have you ensured that you have a unique `name` set? Are you certain that your template path is correct, and that the template exists there?

Can you post the code that is supposed to add this to the content block?